# adding values to a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{"movie_name": {"Split": ["split", "Split"]}}
```

If I try to add values to `movie_name` it updates the value inside it.
What I want to do is if I try to add another value like `"sing"` it should be like the code below:

```
{"movie_name": {"Split": ["split", "Split"], "sing": ["Sing","sing"]}}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your current code? How are you reading this data?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The reason I ask is if you want to map all lower & upper case variations of a title, this isn't necessarily the most efficient way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access the second dict inside your top dict.
This is done by using square brackets. Say your top dict is named a:

`a = { "movie_name": { "Split" : ["split", "Split"] } }`

To access the dict within a, you need to use its key, then you can modify it:

`a["movie_name"]["sing"] = ["Sing","sing"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
myDic['movie_name']['sing'] = ["Sing","sing"]
```